# Connecting two user logins

Tags: support, status-completed

My wife registered as [suzanne](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/users/1641/suzanne) but somehow has ended up answering questions as unregistered user [sstNorwalk](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5199/leveling-a-yard-and-laying-sod) here. I want to help her merge the to ids, ending up with the sstNorwalk icon and the suzanne information. I don't know how to do this.

Does she have two SE ids: one registered here but without the right icon, the other with the right icon but not registered?

Answer (score 4):

I have confirmed that the two are indeed the same user and have gone ahead and merged `sstNorwalk` into [`suzanne`](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/users/1641/suzanne). I found yet another unregistered account as `sstNorwalk` and have merged that too.

```
Oct 20  moderator merges users  id = 1648 into id = 1641 by yoda
Oct 20  moderator merges users  id = 1694 into id = 1641 by yoda
```

You can verify that all the answers are present under `suzanne`.

The icon or the gravatar is handled by gravatar.com, and is associated with her email. The `suzanne` account had a typo in the email entered (two characters were flipped), which is why the system pulled the default gravatar for that account (the orange one). I've now fixed the typo and the account now has the gravatar that was associated with `sstNorwalk`.

---

For future reference, there is really no way for a user to merge their multiple accounts by themselves. There are three ways to get two accounts merged:

- ask a [support](/questions/tagged/support) question on meta like you did and a moderator will merge the accounts after verification.
- raise a moderator flag on one of your posts (or any post, if you have the rep) and explain in your message and link to the other account and a moderator will handle it.
- go to the [help page](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help) (just add `/help` to any SE site's URL) and click on "Merge user profiles" under Account Management. This sends an email to the SE community team (different from the previous two), who will then respond to your request.

Comment: Thanks! This is great!